# Spivak, Calculus, Ch 5 - Limits, Problem **23a: Why can we use the trick $g(x)=\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Problem 22 from Chapter 5 of Spivak's Calculus is as follows:

> Consider the function $f$ with the following property: if $g$ is any
> function for which $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)$ does not exist, then
> $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} [f(x) + g(x)]$ also does not exist. Prove that
> this happens if and only if $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does exist.

Problem 23 is a variation on the above problem that apparently makes it significantly more complex:

> This problem is an analogue of Problem 22 when $f+g$ is replaced by $f \cdot g$. In this case the situation is considerably more complex, and
> the analysis requires several steps.
>
> a) Suppose $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exists and is $\neq 0$. Prove
> that if $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)$ does not exist, then
> $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x)$ also does not exist.

I am interested specifically in this item $a)$. I came up with the same solution as the solution manual I believe. Here is the solution from the solution manual, but the latter is very terse:

> If $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x)$ existed, then $\lim\limits_{x \to
> > 0} g(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} [f(x)g(x)/f(x)]$ would also exist

Here is my solution:

The complete statement that we would like to prove in Problem 23 is

$$\forall f [\forall g(\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x) \implies \nexists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x)) \iff \exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)]$$

Item $a)$ however is similar to one of the conditionals in the biconditional above:

$$\forall f[\exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) \neq 0 \implies \forall g(\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x) \implies \nexists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x))]$$

Here is the proof of this latter statement:

Let $f$ be any function.

Assume $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) \neq 0$.

Let us prove the contraposition of

$$\forall g(\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x) \implies \nexists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x))$$

Which is

$$\forall g(\exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x) \implies \exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x))$$

Let g be any function such that $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x)$, and let this limit be $L$.

**Here is the step that my question is about.**

We can write $g = \frac{fg}{f}$

**But why can we actually do this? What if f can take the value zero?**

Since $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) \neq  0$ then $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{f}$, and since $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x)$ by assumption, we can assert that $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}$ (using a Theorem from the Spivak main text).

Hence $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)$ exists.

By conditional elimination, we can assert that $\forall g(\exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x) \implies \exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x))$, which is the contraposition that we wanted to prove.

Because we assumed that $f$ was arbitrary, by conditional elimination we can assert the initial claim that:

$$\forall f[\exists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) \neq 0 \implies \forall g(\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x) \implies \nexists \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x))]$$

**Why can we write $g = \frac{fg}{f}$ for an arbitrary function $g$?**

To take an example, if $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=x$. Then if we try to write $g(x)=\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}$ we have $g(x)=\frac{0}{0}g(x)$.

**What am I missing about this trick?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example at the end doesn't work because the limit has to be nonzero. And this is the crucial prerequisite. If the limit is nonzero, there is a neighborhood around $0$ where $f$ is nonzero. In that neighborhood the multiplicative inverse of $f$ exists and since we only care about arbitrarily small neighborhoods around $0$, we can use the inverse for evaluating the limit.